# What species of butterfly/moth is this please?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, lepidoptera

[image]

[image]

What species is this please?

It's really tiny. That's an oregano leaf.

Location: United Kingdom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mint moth. We can only see the forewings on this photo. Single gold spot is the giveaway.

Comment: Hi Phil. Thanks for providing an answer. Please provide more detail and links/citations to reputable sources that support your claim (and preferably a picture from a reputable source as well). Unsupported and one-line answers will be downvoted or deleted. Please edit accordingly.